# Is there another method to declare new activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android

Normally I will declare a new activity in AndroidManifest.xml as below:
Let's say my new activity is Tutorial.java.

```
<activity android:name=".Tutorial"></activity>
```

But I found an example, the developer not declare the new activity as above. The code is list as below:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.dezine.thebasics"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".myMain"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".myMenu"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.dezine.thebasics.CLEARSCREEN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

**myMenu.java**

```
package com.dezine.thebasics;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class myMenu extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.click);

    Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.dezine.thebasics.TUTORIAL"));
            mpButtonClick.start();
        }
    });
    }
}
```

The above code is work fine at beginning(mean I don't change anything in AndroidManifest.xml) but it will come out error after I modify something in Manifest.xml. eg. I change the SDK version.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5236): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.dezine.thebasics.TUTORIAL }
```

Please tell me how it work. Thank you.

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(myMenu.this,ActivityNameYouWantToOpen.class); is the way to open another activity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a difference between **TUTORIAL** and **Tutorial**

Let me give you more detail.

You have written below code to start activity:

```
  startActivity(new Intent("com.dezine.thebasics.TUTORIAL"));
```

But you have defined activity inside AndroidManifest.xml as:

```
<activity android:name=".Tutorial"></activity>
```

And thats why you are getting this exception.

Comment: -1. Yes there is a difference between TUTORIAL and Tutorial. One is an Activity while the other is part of the action name and there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @binW my dear dont downvote blindly, first try to understand the short-answer what was my meaning actually.

Comment: right. But his code creates an intent using a string i.e new Intent("com.dezine.thebasics.TUTORIAL"); and the constructor for Intent which takes String argument will consider the string as action name not the class name. So your answer is still wrong. Take a look http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String)

Comment: @PareshMayani - Don't worry dude ! There are few exceptional rude people in this world ! :P :) I gone through your answer. Helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your all comment.
@binW - Your link is helpful.

Answer (score -1):

There is no activity defined for handling the action "com.dezine.thebasics.TUTORIAL". There is an activity for handling "com.dezine.thebasics.CLEARSCREEN" though. Are you sure you are not using wrong action name. Either you are missing an activity definition from manifest or you are using wrong action name in code. Try changing the

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.dezine.thebasics.TUTORIAL"));
```

to

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.dezine.thebasics.CLEARSCREEN"));
```